# add click Listner in each item of row in Listview

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

i want add clickable link in android listview item, i have 5 item in each row of listview and i want only two item make clickable and open sholud in webview using putextras() intents i am using custom adapter pls any one hlep me.

suppose "link 1" is: "view Proofing"(proofinglink) (in textview) and "link 2" is : "Get More Detail"(sitelink) i want when i click link 1 then it should open in webview behind his own given url . and when i click on link 2: it should also open in webview in his own given url. using putextras() intents 
 here is my code.

```
           package tipster;

            import java.io.BufferedReader;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.io.InputStream;
            import java.io.InputStreamReader;
            import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
            import java.net.URI;
            import java.net.URISyntaxException;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            import newsletter.Latest_list;
            import newsletter.Webview_news;

            import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
            import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
            import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
            import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
            import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
            import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
            import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
            import org.json.JSONArray;
            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.app.Dialog;
            import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
            import android.net.NetworkInfo;
            import android.os.AsyncTask;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.AdapterView;
            import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
            import android.widget.ListView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import com.example.newapp.R;

           public class Tipster extends Activity {
           ListView lv;
           ArrayList<Tipster_list>listitem;
           String title;
           String serviceUrl;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_tipster);

         if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
         // Execution here
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Network is Available!",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        execute();

        title="Free Tip - Betfans";

        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_tipsterID);

        listitem=new ArrayList<Tipster_list>();
    }

 else {

   Toast.makeText(this, "Network is unavailable!",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }


}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    boolean isAvailable = false;
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    return isAvailable;
}

private void execute() {

    serviceUrl ="http://mobile.betfan.com/api/?      
  Action=top&type=default&key=MEu07MgiuWgXwJOo7Oe1aHL0yM8VvP";

    //Toast.makeText(LatestNews.this, serviceUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  


    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Tipster.this, "Please
           while wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            String dataString = jsonObject.toString();

            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new 
               ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", dataString));

            String result = null;

            try{



                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet();

                URI apiurl = new URI(serviceUrl);

                httpRequest.setURI(apiurl);

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();


            loadingDialog.dismiss();

                JSONObject respObject;
                try {
                    respObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    String active = respObject.getString("status_message");


                    if(active.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                     JSONArray array =     
                   respObject.getJSONArray("response");
                            for (int i =0; i<array.length();i++){

                         JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                         String icon= jsonObject.getString("image");
                         String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                         String total = jsonObject.getString("total");
                         String proofinglink = 
                       jsonObject.getString("proofinglink");
                         String sitelink = jsonObject.getString("sitelink");

                          listitem.add(new   
                  Tipster_list(icon,name,"+"+total,proofinglink,sitelink));

                        }
                         lv.setAdapter(new Tipster_adapter(Tipster.this,  
                 listitem));    

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(Tipster.this, "services received 
                  Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String getName=listitem.get(arg2).getName();
                        String 
                 getproofing=listitem.get(arg2).getProofinglink();
                        String getsite=listitem.get(arg2).getSitelink();







                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
             Tipster_webview.class);

                         intent.putExtra("gettproofing_URl",getproofing);
                         intent.putExtra("getsiteURL",getsite);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });

        }

    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute();

  }
```

i want "proofinglink" and "sitelink" should be clickable and open in webview

here is custom adapter

```
                public class Tipster_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
                Context context;
          ArrayList<Tipster_list>tipslist;

                public Tipster_adapter(Context context,
     ArrayList<Tipster_list> tipslist) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.tipslist = tipslist;
 }



  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return tipslist.size();
 }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)
    context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tipster_adapter
                 ,null); 


        ImageView icon=
      (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_tipsterIconID);

        TextView name=(TextView) 
          convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_tipsterID);
        TextView total=(TextView) 
     convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_tipsterID);
        TextView proofingLink=(TextView) 
   convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_proofinglink_tipsterID);
        TextView siteLink=(TextView) 
   convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sitelink_tipsterID);

        Tipster_list services=tipslist.get(position);
        Picasso.with(context).load(services.getImage()).into(icon);
        Log.d("Url",services.getImage());
        name.setText(services.getName());
        total.setText(services.getTotal());
        proofingLink.setText(services.getProofinglink());
        siteLink.setText(services.getSitelink());

        }



    return convertView;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is ok you need to add a listener in your adapter for the view on which you want to fire an intent for example

```
inside your adapter getview method paste this code like this

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Tipster_list services=tipslist.get(position);
    if(services!=null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_adapter,null);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_tipsterIconID);
        TextView name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_tipsterID);
        TextView total=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_total_tipsterID);
        TextView proofingLink=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_proofinglink_tipsterID);
        TextView siteLink=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sitelink_tipsterID);
        Picasso.with(context).load(services.getImage()).into(icon);
        Log.d("Url",services.getImage());
        name.setText(services.getName());
        total.setText(services.getTotal());
        proofingLink.setText(services.getProofinglink());
        siteLink.setText(services.getSitelink());
        convertView.setTag(position);
        String getName=services.getName();
        final String getproofing=services.getProofinglink();
        final String getsite=services.getSitelink();
        proofingLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tipster_webview.class);
                 intent.putExtra("gettproofing_URl",getproofing);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        siteLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tipster_webview.class);
                             intent.putExtra("site",getsite);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
        }



return convertView;
}
```

Comment: pls write me some code and tell me where i paste this code which lines,  i am new ,thanx @Mehroz Munir

Comment: inside your adapter getview method paste this code like this

Comment: not helpful in "convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_tipsterID" why need to write txt_name_tipsterID? except that also gives other many error when i pasted your code in adapter. @Mehroz Munir

Comment: wring txt_name_tipsterID just for example you write the id here of the view on which you want to set the listener

Comment: i think the error was because i was using onItemClickListener replaced it with setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { check my code now

Comment: ok i think it should be in  "public class Tipster extends Activity {}" instead of adapter, because   intent.putExtra("gettproofing_URl",getproofing); is already used in Tipster class ! not in adapter. if i write in adapter then how get value of "getproofing" ? getproofing get values from json in tipster class pls update your naswer

Comment: no use it in adapter , u can use context if it is giving error when startactivity

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Tipster_webview.class);
                intent.putExtra("gettproofing_URl",getproofing);
                intent.putExtra("getplatform", getsite);
                context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: your Tipster_webview class should also be public to access it in adapter

Comment: patesd but gives error . error no.1"he method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments ()" error no.2 "getproofing cannot be resolved to a variable "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112644/discussion-between-mehroz-munir-and-saim).

Answer (score 0):

```
    TextView proofingLink=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_proofinglink_tipsterID);

    proofingLink.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {

       String url = services.getProofinglink();
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
       startActivity(i);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView proofingLink=(TextView)
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_proofinglink_tipsterID);
proofingLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}); 
TextView siteLink=(TextView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sitelink_tipsterID);
siteLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: i get "proofinglink" and "sitelink" form json then how i bind them with findview by id and SetOnclickLister. pls proper help me i am new thanks @shubham

Comment: write this code in getView() method and in that method you have links also.

Comment: i also write in getview but not help full it gves that error error no.1 "Duplicate local variable proofingLink" error no.2 "The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})"